# Having a class provide default XmlElementName

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have set of classes I am trying to serialize as part of this specification: http://open511.org/root.html

```
public class Link
{
    public Link()
    {

    }

    public Link(string url, string rel = "self")
    {
        Url = url;
        Rel = rel;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("rel")]
    public string Rel { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("href")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Service
{
    private Link _serviceTypeUrl;

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public Link ServiceTypeUrl
    {
        get { return _serviceTypeUrl; }
        set
        {
            _serviceTypeUrl = value;
            _serviceTypeUrl.Rel = "service_type";
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public Link Url { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("supported_versions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("supported_version")]
    public List<SupportedVersion> SupportedVersions { get; set; }
}
```

It won't let me have two properties with the same XMLElement. Is there a way to do this?

I would originally have loved to have the link class specify that it is always to use the element name "link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to achieve isn't supported. Your alternatives are:

1. Use different element names to serialize your attributes
2. Use a collection to hold all your `Link`s. This makes querying data hard
   in some cases, but I believe will give you something similar to what you want.

**Sources**

- [SO answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891154/632736)
- [SO answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645988/632736)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by FreeAsInBeer's answer I stored them in a list and wrote a custom insert to prevent duplicate insertion.

```
public class Service
{
    private List<Link> _links;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Link ServiceTypeUrl
    {
        get { return Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Rel == "service_type"); }
        set
        {
            var tempLink = value;
            tempLink.Rel = "service_type";
            Links.RemoveAll(l => l.Rel == tempLink.Rel); // prevent duplicate rel
            Links.Add(tempLink);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Link Url
    {
        get { return Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Rel == "self"); }
        set
        {
            var tempLink = value;
            tempLink.Rel = "self";
            Links.RemoveAll(l => l.Rel == tempLink.Rel); // prevent duplicate rel
            Links.Add(tempLink);
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public List<Link> Links
    {
        get { return _links ?? (_links = new List<Link>()); }
        set { _links = value; }
    }

    [XmlArray("supported_versions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("supported_version")]
    public List<SupportedVersion> SupportedVersions { get; set; }
}
```